# Show (Visible/Hidden NOT Show/Hide) HTML Element based on form select box selection

Tags: javascript, forms, hidden, visible, drop-down-menu

The following worked perfectly for my needs. Took the state of a checkbox and did wonderful things for me; Made 3 different form elements visible (vs. show/hide) based on checkbox checked or not checked. Simple, I guess. Then again, I base "simple" on how symmetrical the code looks and if it's less that 10 lines. Other than that, I'm lost. However, I've officially given up on messing around with IE's checkbox border issue and X-browser alignment yippeedoodles. I want pixel perfect the hard way. But I lost that battle. But rather than get into any discussion about that, I need to accomplish the same thing using a form select box as I was able to do with the checkboxes (below):

```
<form id="form">
<input id="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="showhideid" />
</form>



#IdOne, #IdTwo, #IdThree (visibility:hidden;}


function showhideid()
{
    if (document.form.checkbox.checked)
    {   
        document.getElementById("IdOne").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("IdTwo").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("IdThree").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("IdFour").setAttribute("class", "required");

    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("IdOne").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("IdTwo").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("IdThree").style.visibility = "hidden";   
        document.getElementById("IdFour").setAttribute("class", "");
    }
}
```

Now, if I can accomplish the same thing using a select box (below), I will die a happy man.

This is as far as I've gotten. I'm super dizzy from reading Jquery/CSS man pages and I just can't put it all together.

```
<html>

<form id="form">

<select name="SelectBox">
<option>Make a Choice</option>
<option value="Value1">Selection1</option>
<option value="Value2">Selection2</option>
<option value="Value3">Selection3</option>
</select>

<label id="IdOne" for="input1">MeAndMyInputAreInvisibleByDesign</label>
<input id="IdTwo" name="input1" type="text">

<span id="IdThree">Im Not In display:none Mode I'm In visibility:hidden Mode. Big difference."
</span>

<input id="IdFour" name="input2" type="text" class="I have none, but I will soon. I hope" />

</form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the `select` tag:

```
<select name="SelectBox">
<option>Make a Choice</option>
<option value="IdTwo">Selection1</option> <!-- the value should be the id of the input field -->
<option value="IdThree">Selection2</option>
<option value="IdFour">Selection3</option>
</select>
```

Now you must give a selector class to each element you want to show/hide:

```
<input id="IdTwo" name="input1" type="text" class="toggle">
<span id="IdThree" class="toggle">
   Im Not In display:none Mode I'm In visibility:hidden Mode. Big difference."
</span>
<input id="IdFour" name="input2" type="text" class="toggle" />
```

Now look at the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('input[name="SelectBox"]').change(function(){
  jQuery('.toggle').css({"visibility":"hidden"});//Hide all
  jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).val()).css({"visibility":"visible"});
 });
});
```

Comment: Ya, the first one, below, worked after I stuck Jquery link in the HTML. Was this one doing something different? I noticed a few syntax changes and an addition or two. Does .toggle just tell x to simply change states, as the word implies? Seems night and day to that simple thing above that I posted. Was straight forward. I'm not familiar with any reserved words, conventions, etc. JS is breand new to me, literally. But I'm enjoying what it cans seemingly do. The problem is I don't know where to start for what I need it for. :)

Comment: @adg Yes the toggle class is just to use as a selector. It could be anything like "xyz". I just tried to make code more understandable. Didn't change anything as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<html>

<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="IdOne" class="toggle" />
<input type="text" id="IdTwo" class="toggle" />
<input type="text" id="IdThree" class="toggle" />
<select name="SelectBox" id="selectBox">
<option value="0">Make a Choice</option>
<option value="IdOne">First element</option>
<option value="IdTwo">Second element</option>
<option value="IdThree">Third element</option>
</select>

</html>
```

this in javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#selectBox").change(function(){
  jQuery(".toggle").hide();
  jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).val()).show();
 });
});
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what that does. Anyway, upon reading my own "title", I realized I stuck "Jquery" in there. Jquery isn't necc. Any Jscript will do, I'm sure. I've been reading some much I've branded, in my mind, JaveScript=Jquery. Like Kleenex is to Tissue. My apologies.

Comment: Hide/Show will break the form, hence me wanting the Visible/Hidden method. I'm just not familiar with how to apply that to HTML form Select boxes.

Comment: Okay, in that case you can replace `show()` with `css({"visibility":"visible"})` and `hide()` with `css({"visibility":"hidden"})`

Comment: Erroring on me. Looking at it. Exhausted.

Comment: Now, asking if the plug was plugged in. :) I wasn't loading Jquery. Anyway, thanks so much for this. I'll have to play with it and see if I can figure a way to change class type AND visible at the same time. Also, is there a way to do it without having to load Jquery. The Javascript above didn't rely on it. Seems like a tad overkill. But I have no idea because I'm on hour 2 of working with Javascript. Have never touched it.

Comment: Not to chit chat in these places, but whats the URL to that site (blue background) where one can paste code in 4 diff panels and run all of it. I've seen ref to it here all the time.

Comment: JS Fiddle. Got it. Whew. <See, I wasn't kidding. I'm new> :)